# order by slows query down massively

Tags: sql-server, performance

using sql server 2014; ((SP1-CU3) (KB3094221) Oct 10 2015 x64

I have the following query

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.table1 t1

                    LEFT JOIN dbo.table2 t2 ON t2.trade_id = t1.tradeNo
                    LEFT JOIN dbo.table3 t3 ON t3.TradeReportID = t1.tradeNo                                                                                                
                    order by t1.tradeNo
```

there are ~70k, 35k and 73k rows in t1,t2 and t3 respectively.

When I omit the `order by` this query executes in 3 seconds with 73k rows.

As written the query took 8.5 *minutes* to return ~50k rows (I since stopped it)

Switching the order of the `LEFT JOIN`s makes a difference:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.table1 t1

                    LEFT JOIN dbo.table3 t3 ON t3.TradeReportID = t1.tradeNo                                                                                                
                    LEFT JOIN dbo.table2 t2 ON t2.trade_id = t1.tradeNo                     
                    order by t1.tradeNo
```

This now runs in 3 seconds.

I dont have any indexes on the tables. Adding indexes `t1.tradeNo` and `t2.trade_id` and `t3.TradeReportID` has no effect.
Running the query with only one left join (both scenarios) in combination with the `order by` is fast.

Its fine for me to swap the order of the `LEFT JOIN`s but this doesnt go far to explaining *why* this happens and under what scenarios it may happen again

The estimated exectuion plan is: (slow)
[image]

(exclamation mark details)
[image]

**VS**

Switching the order of the left joins (fast):

[image]

which I note are markedly different but I cannot interpret these to explain the performance difference

## UPDATE

It appears the addition of the `order by` clause results in the execution plan using the Table Spool (lazy spool) vs NOT using this in the fast query.
If I turn off the table spool via `DBCC RULEOFF ('BuildSpool');` this 'fixes' the speed but according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26314632/query-is-extremely-slow-due-to-lazy-index-spool) this isnt recommended and cannot do it per query anyway

## UPDATE 2

One of the columns returned (`table3.Text`] has type `varchar(max)`) - If this is changed to `nvarchar(512)` then the original (slow) query is now fast - ie the execution plan now decides to not use the Table Spool - also note that even tho the type is `varchar(max)` the field values are NULL for every one of the rows. This is now fixable but I am none the wiser

## UPDATE 3

Warnings in the execution plan stated

> Type conversion in expression (CONVERT_IMPLICIT(nvarchar(50),[t2].[trade_id],0)) may affect "CardinalityEstimate" in query plan choice, ...

`t1.tradeNo` is `nvarchar(21)` - the other two are `varchar(50)` - after altering the latter two to the same as the first the problem disappears! (leaving varchar(max) as stated in UPDATE 2 unchanged)

Given this problem goes away when either UPDATE 2 or UPDATE 3 are rectified I would guess that its a combination of the query optimizer using a temp table (table spool) for a column that has an unbounded size - very interesting despite the `nvarchar(max)` column having no data.

Comment: Check the execution plans before and after switching left joins. Is there any difference? What kind of join is used (Hash/Nested Loop/Merge) in both of them?

Comment: Ah! As can be second from second plan, there is a lot of parallelism in the plan. Also, the cost of Index scans on table3 is reduced to 0 from 49% (Gone is the Lazy table spool too). In case of LEFT joins, order will obviously have effect on query processing because each subsequent join is made with the output from previous join.

Comment: `In case of LEFT joins, order will obviously have effect on query processing because each subsequent join is made with the output from previous join` sure but either way the first `LEFT JOIN` produces roughly the same number of rows to be joined with the 2nd `LEFT JOIN` - also its only the addition of the `order by` that slows the original down, not the joins themselves

Comment: The query optimizer is not working correctly. Try to regenerate the statistics, otherwise look for a potential patch, because this looks buggy.

Comment: In the past I came across a similar issue. Instead of Left Joins, I changed the query to use Left Outer Joins which boosted the performance.

Comment: There is no difference between a left join and a left outer join. They are the same thing

Comment: You have an exclamation mark on your select operator. If you press F4 do you get more details?

Comment: You said said that adding an index to tradeno made no difference, however did you also add indexes to trade_id on table2 and TradeReportID on table3?

Comment: @Dijkgraaf adding indexes to all 3 tables - has no effect

Comment: So there is no 'warnings' section in that tooltip? See example halfway down here: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2013/01/15/sql-server-introduction-of-showplan-warning/. I think your first task is to compare the data between the two queries because functionally they are different. The other difference is the fast one only uses merge joins (fast) and the slow one includes a nested loop (often not as fast). Even though the percentage is small, it's not always accurate. Another thing to try is press CTRL-M, run the query to completion, and check the actual and estimated row counts

Comment: `I think your first task is to compare the data between the two queries because functionally they are different` <-- I'm not saying they are not but could you please elaborate on that ? the end result will be the same (and is the same when you omit the `order by`

Comment: This sounds like you need to generate or rerun statistics.

Comment: One thing, have you tried running select * vs select columns?

Comment: @brykneval yes its one of the columns that causes issues. will update post with details

Comment: My mistake they are functionally the same. I thought you were joining T1 > T2 > T3, which in an outer join makes a big difference to T1 > T3 > T2. Instead you are joining T1 > T2 & T1 > T3 in both cases. This is very suprising, given that this _should_ yield the same query plan. With regards to the exclamation mark symbol - is there any warnings at the bottom of that tooltip? That's what I'm really after.

Comment: Hmmm I just reproduced on some tables here. join order shouldn't change the query plan for queries that are functionally the same.... but for outer joins they do... and I don't know why.

Comment: *I dont have any indexes on the tables* , *varchar(max)* , `SELECT *`   - and you really wonder why this query is slow? The main point here is bad table design! Get rid of that and afterwards you can try to speed up the query!

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid thanks - that uncovered yet another issue. see UPDATE 3

Comment: Awesome and I'm not making this up - I now remember reading something about table spools and implicit casts some time ago. I'm still trying to work out why a left outer join changes order though

Comment: @CeOnSql did you read the part where I said the query was quick? Your comment does nothing to explain what is going on

Comment: Do you know how often i (and i am sure many of us here) hear that "it was quick", "it just stopped working", "yesterday everything was ok".... What i want to tell you is: It's best practice to have a solid base before you start to write queries. And that's what good table design is about.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your likely best fix is to **make sure both sides of your joins have the same datatype**. There's no need for one to be `varchar` and the other `nvarchar`.

This is a class of problems that comes up quite frequently in DBs. The database is **assuming the wrong thing** about the *composition* of the data it's about to deal with. The costs shown in your *estimated* execution plan are likely a long way from what you'd get in your *actual* plan. We all make mistakes and really it would be good if SQL Server learned from its own but currently it doesn't. It will estimate a 2 second return time despite being immediately proven wrong again and again. To be fair, I don't know of any DBMS which has machine-learning to do better.

### **Where your query is fast**

The hardest part is done up front by sorting table3. That means it can do an efficient merge join which in turn means it has no reason to be lazy about spooling.

### **Where it's slow**

Having an ID that refers to the same thing stored as two different types and data lengths shouldn't ever be necessary and will never be a good idea for an ID. In this case `nvarchar` in one place `varchar` in another. When that makes it fail to get a cardinality estimate that's the key flaw and here's why:

The optimizer is hoping to require only a few unique rows from table3. Just a handful of options like "Male", "Female", "Other". That would be what is known as "low cardinality". So imagine tradeNo actually contained IDs for genders for some weird reason. Remember, it's you with your human skills of contextualisation, who knows that's very unlikely. The DB is blind to that. So here is what it expects to happen: As it executes the query the first time it encounters the ID for "Male" it will lazily fetch the data associated (like the word "Male") and put it in the spool. Next, because it's sorted it expects just a lot more males and to simply re-use what it has already put in the spool.

Basically, it plans to fetch the data from tables 1 and 2 in a few big chunks stopping once or twice to fetch new details from table 3. In practice the stopping isn't occasional. In fact, it may even be stopping for *every single row* because there are lots of different IDs here. The **lazy spool is like going upstairs to get one small thing at a time**. Good if you think you just need your wallet. Not so good if you're moving house, in which case you'll want a big box (the eager spool).

The likely reason that shrinking the size of the field in table3 helped is that it meant it estimated less of a comparative benefit in doing the lazy spool over a full sort up front. With `varchar` it doesn't know how much data there is, just how much there could potentially be. The bigger the potential chunks of data that need shuffling, the more physical work needs doing.

### What you can do to avoid in future

Make your table schema and indexes reflect the real shape of the data.

- If an ID can be `varchar` in one table then it's very unlikely to need the extra characters available in `nvarchar` for another table. Avoid the need for conversions on IDs and also use integers instead of characters where possible.
- Ask yourself if any of these tables need tradeNo to be filled in for
  all rows. If so, make it not nullable on that table. Next, ask if the
  ID should be unique for any of these tables and set it up as such in
  the appropriate index. Unique is the definition of maximum cardinality
  so it won't make that mistake again.

Nudge in the right direction with join order.

- The order you have your joins in the SQL is a signal to the database about how powerful/difficult you expect each join to be. (Sometimes as a human you know more. e.g. if querying for 50 year old astronauts you know that filtering for astronauts would be the first filter to apply but maybe begin with the age when searching for 50 year office workers.) The heavy stuff should come first. It will ignore you if it thinks it has the information to know better but in this case it's relying on your knowledge.

If all else fails

- A possible fix would be to `INCLUDE` all the fields you'll need from table3 in the index on TradeReportId. The reason the indexes couldn't help so much already is that they make it easy to identify *how* to re-sort but it still hasn't been physically *done*. That is work it was hoping to optimize with a lazy spool but if the data were included it would be already available so no work to optimize.

Comment: Very nice answer.

Answer (score -1):

Having indexes on a table are key to speeding up retrieval of data. Start with this and then retry your query to see if the speed is improved using 'ORDER BY'

Comment: did you read everything i posted? including this bit
`Adding indexes t1.tradeNo and t2.trade_id and t3.TradeReportID has no effect` - I dont know who upvoted this either they didnt read either

Comment: The query *is quick* - its slow only when the `order by` is added and even then can be made quick again by changing the order of the LEFT JOIN

Comment: For this to have worked all the data for Table3 would have needed to be included in the index.